# Certificates management in Android 4.2

Tags: android, certificate

I have a tablet running Android 4.2 with multiple users configured. I want to install certificates which can be accessed by the secondary user (basically I want to configure an Email account in the secondary user which requires certificates). I installed certificates in the primary user. But, when I try to access them in the secondary user, the dialog doesn't display the installed certificates.

I also tried modifying the Settings application to show the "Install certificates" option in the secondary user. But, clicking that option shows a toast that "Only owner can install certificates". I went a step further and changed CertInstaller to allow secondary users to install certificates. But, it fails when Android attempts to write the certificates to /data/misc/keychain directory.

My question is that, is /data/misc/keychain directory only accessible (read/write access) to applications running inside the primary user (owner). If yes, then how the access control is enforced?